# Clean URL Title

Tags: php, regex

Good Morning Everyone. I have a blog with the title "THE LAST JEDI Will Rock You (Review)"

I have a php function

```
function get_url_text( $string, $separator = '-')
{
    $accents_regex = '~&([a-z]{1,2})(?:acute|cedil|circ|grave|lig|orn|ring|slash|th|tilde|uml);~i';
    $special_cases = array( '&' => 'and', "'" => '');
    $string = mb_strtolower( trim( $string ), 'UTF-8' );
    $string = str_replace( array_keys($special_cases), array_values( $special_cases), $string );
    $string = preg_replace( $accents_regex, '$1', htmlentities( $string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' ) );
    $string = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9]/u", "$separator", $string);
    $string = preg_replace("/[$separator]+/u", "$separator", $string);
    return $string;
}
```

After I run the title through the function.

`get_url_text("THE LAST JEDI Will Rock You (Review)");`

I get the result like below:

**the-last-jedi-will-rock-you-review-**

So it look like the function turn the last character ')' into a '-'

I want my result to be

**the-last-jedi-will-rock-you-review**

without the '-' at the end. What changes do I need to make in the function to make this happen?

Comment: `trim($str, '-')`

Comment: `rtrim($str,'-')` ?

Answer (score 2):

Either do `return trim($string,'-');` Or do `rtrim($str,'-');`

Reference:-

[trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)

[rtrim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you could vastly simplify your approach to

```
<?php
$title  = "THE LAST JEDI Will Rock You (Review)";
$url     = rtrim(strtolower(preg_replace('~\W+~', '-', $title)), '-');
echo $url;
# the-last-jedi-will-rock-you-review
?>
```

Mind the `\W+` here which looks for non-word characters and replaces them with `-`.

Comment: Or without trim functionality `strtolower(preg_replace(['~\W++(?!\Z)~', '~\W++$|^\W++~'], ['-'], $title));`

Comment: While your suggestion works with the sample input string.  It definitely under performs for all of the fringe cases that the OP's method seems to concern itself with.  http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/56b7a6832a56acea5adcfd25e7c135f4aa77a3a4